# Convert 64Bit Double to 32Bit Float Node.Js

Tags: node.js, type-conversion, double, floating-accuracy

I'm reading 64bit-doubles from a buffer by the function: http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_readdoublele_offset_noassert .

Is it possible to round these 64-bit-values to 32-bit-values in an efficient way?

Thx.

Answer (score 1):

In Node.js 0.11 with the `-harmony_maths` flag you can simply use `Math.fround()`:

```
Math.PI - Math.fround(Math.PI) // -8.742278012618954e-8
```

In Node.js 0.10.25 use `Float32Array`:

```
var fa = new Float32Array(1);
fa[0] = Math.PI
Math.PI - fa[0] // -8.742278012618954e-8
```

See [Efficient float32 arithmetic in JavaScript](https://blog.mozilla.org/javascript/2013/11/07/efficient-float32-arithmetic-in-javascript/)